# Default vim colorscheme in Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, vim, colors

In every Linux system I install or I happen to log into I want to use the same vim colorscheme, e.g. the default one Debian uses, because I usually use Debian and I like the default colorscheme. What's its name? I need the name to specify it in the `$HOME/.vimrc` file of other systems:

```
colorscheme whatever
```

The problem is that even `default` is not the correct name in Debian, in fact if I open a file in one of my Debian systems without a `$HOME/.vimrc` file (so no `colorscheme` command at all), I get this:

[image: no colorscheme command]

then, while I'm inside `vim`, I type the `:colorscheme` command, and it replies `default`. However if I create a `$HOME/.vimrc` file with `colorscheme default` in it, in the same Debian system, and then I open the same file, I get this instead:

[image: colorscheme default in Debian]

I want the first colorscheme in every other `vim` I use, but I have no clue about how to specify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found `/usr/share/vim/vim81/colors` directory, that contains only 19 colorschemes: not that hard to bruteforce after all. I've tried all of them one after the other and I finally found `ron` to be the real default one, despite `colorscheme default` not loading `ron`...

Why `colorscheme default` doesn't load the real default, or why the real default goes by the name of `ron` and `default` is a non-default choice, is beyond me: maybe Debian exhausted the symlinks pool, so renaming the `default` file as `classic` or something and symlinking `default` to `ron` would have broken the whole system, but it doesn't really matter anymore...

```
:colorscheme ron
```

is what I was looking for.

EDIT: I've asked this same question on the Debian user mailing list, and I've received the correct answer. The `default` colorscheme isn't detecting my dark background when run inside my `xfce4-terminal` (and maybe others), so it uses dark colors as if it were on a light background.

Issuing the `:set bg=dark` command reverts the `default` colorscheme to light colors, which are the default `vim` colors on dark background in absence of a `:colorscheme` command, and they are the same as `ron` too, at least as long as my `bash` scripts are concerned.

Comment: Thank you, I also was wondering what was going on..

Answer (score 0):

It can be really challenging for new users:

1.make sure you have a `~/.vimrc` file in your Home directory. If not create one:

```sh
vi ~/.vimrc
```

and make sure you have these two entries:

```
syntax on
colorscheme name_of_your_colorscheme
```

2. then jump into this folder and give all color schemes in there the right owner for your user:

cd /usr/share/vim/vim82/colors

```sh
sudo chown username.usergroup *
```

3. reboot and now you should have that color scheme active.

---

On Debian 12 you can simply

```
sudo vi /usr/share/vim/vim90/defaults.vim
```

and add the following under "syntax on"

```
colorscheme your_colorscheme_name
```

Comment: It appears that the OP is using vim81. So you must be a bot, not to have figured that out. Which means that I can't trust this answer without trying.

Comment: This "answer" does not even try to address my question, which, btw, I already answered three years ago...

Comment: upvoted as the `syntax on` line made my day.